# How to correctly read and fix memory usage of a web application in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

I'm debugging my javascript web application consisting of a package of ~24MB of images & sounds. I'm not particularly generating a lot of data in my app so the memory usage shouldn't be any higher than 100MB at most.

When checking memory using the chrome profiler, a heap snapshot reports 30MB of usage. Looking at various numbers also reports much the same numbers.

My problem is when looking at memory reports in the Chrome Task Manager, it says the tab is using between 400-600 MB of private bytes of memory. When looking at chrome://memory-internals/ , the report is 400 MB of private bytes and 24 MB in 'V8 Used / Alloc' memory. I'm guessing that the private bytes is the memory used by the JS runtime and V8 the memory of my application.

Now, my question is how can I reduce the memory footprint of the JS runtime ? I'm trying to make my app compatible on mobile and iOS is shutting my app down when loading because I'm using too much RAM. I understand the problem might entirely be on my shoulders but I'm looking for common causes of such a high memory impact on the runtime side of things.

Comment: chrome will use more memory than the files contain. just because a file is `X` mb in size doesn't mean it will take `X` mb of ram, after decompression, etc.

Comment: I did some tests for this. I put a 'debugger;' instruction on my javascript entry point. Doing a step-by-step of the lines on my app and looking at the task manager shows me that more or less each step my app gains upward of 6 KB.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr: My issue was caused by an extension.**

I had somewhat similar problems with one of my applications using around 150MB of RAM, while it should've been way smaller. (The entire folder it was run from was 1.85MB and although a WebSocket connection was kept open, no data was being transferred and no fancy XHR things were happening in the background, which could be explained by [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69783).)

After looking around for quite a bit of time I started to get frustrated, because I couldn't figure out where that usage was coming from. I enabled the "JavaScript memory" column in the Chrome Task Manager, recorded timelines, checked heap profiles and all these to no avail. Every source that was able to measure JavaScript's memory usage has shown me around 20MB, but the built in task manager of Windows and Chrome's task manager agreed that the entire tab started using around 30MB of memory after a refresh and slowly climbed up to around 150MB.

Suddenly I had an idea to think about my extensions, and I have realized that I had [livepage](https://github.com/MikeRogers0/LivePage) running on that tab. As soon as I disabled it this anomaly went away, so I would recommend checking their extensions for anybody experiencing chrome memory issues!